# Can't Determine Reason for Crash from Xcode Crash Log

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, crash-reports

I had a user running my app on his iPhone 5. He performed a backup with iTunes. Bought a new iPhone 6S and restored from his iTunes backup.

When he launches my app it immediately crashes during launch. I got the crash logs from him, but there is no error message. It's crashing during the auto-generated -applicationDocumentsDirectory function in my AppDelegate.

```
- (NSURL *)applicationDocumentsDirectory
{
    return [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
}
```

Is there any way for me to determine what actually went wrong to see if it's something I can fix?

```
Incident Identifier: 3A0D56CA-EEAF-4F5A-8D16-D182E61034D5
CrashReporter Key:   9f4ce42b70e98d925f135c618394817f9451767b
Hardware Model:      iPhone8,1
Process:             MyApp [1198]
Path:                /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXX/MyApp.app/MyApp
Identifier:          com.inadaydevelopment.myapp
Version:             1.0.1 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2015-10-02 14:30:25.25 -0700
Launch Time:         2015-10-02 14:30:25.25 -0700
OS Version:          iOS 9.0.1 (13A405)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000019950b1e0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001995d4f0c pthread_kill + 112
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000019947eb78 abort + 140
3   MyApp                           0x000000010001ef7c -[AppDelegate applicationDocumentsDirectory] (AppDelegate.m:517)
4   MyApp                           0x000000010001eae8 -[AppDelegate managedObjectContext] (AppDelegate.m:430)
5   MyApp                           0x000000010002d004 -[BaseViewController awakeFromNib] (BaseViewController.m:54)
6   UIKit                           0x00000001890e6058 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 2188
7   UIKit                           0x0000000189324ea0 -[UIStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:] + 196
8   UIKit                           0x0000000189325000 -[UIStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController] + 68
9   UIKit                           0x0000000188edd178 -[UIApplication _loadMainStoryboardFileNamed:bundle:] + 108
10  UIKit                           0x0000000188caee40 -[UIApplication _loadMainInterfaceFile] + 264
11  UIKit                           0x0000000188edc068 -[UIApplication _runWithMainScene:transitionContext:completion:] + 1316
12  UIKit                           0x0000000188ed9300 -[UIApplication workspaceDidEndTransaction:] + 168
13  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d7737ec -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 184
14  FrontBoardServices              0x000000018d773b6c -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] + 56
15  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018369c5a4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24
16  CoreFoundation                  0x000000018369c038 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 540
17  CoreFoundation                  0x0000000183699d38 __CFRunLoopRun + 724
18  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001835c8dc0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 384
19  UIKit                           0x0000000188ca80c8 -[UIApplication _run] + 460
20  UIKit                           0x0000000188ca2f60 UIApplicationMain + 204
21  MyApp                           0x000000010001bdd0 main (main.m:16)
22  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001993ee8b8 start + 4
```

Comment: looks like the app is looking for some files in document directory and unfortunately they are not in the app doc directory!!!!

Comment: It's actually just looking for the documents directory itself, but if those directories aren't there it should just return nil and operating on nil is never supposed to crash.

Comment: Are you able to reproduce this in the 6S simulator?

Comment: look at the path /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/XXX....and see if there are any folders existed or not

Comment: why does the app delegate called after the call to BaseViewController ? IS this expected?

Comment: @Mr.T it's a class method that gets called when you access the managedObjectContext for the first time. Perfectly normal behaviour, and it's from the code auto-generated by Xcode when you use CoreData.

Comment: could it be, that you store the documents path in a file and use it later for downloading? So after the reinstall from iTunes the path did change for sure. That could be the problem. I ran into such an issue also. I stored the path of my Videos and after reinstall from iCloud i couldn't use them anymore.try to check on the beginning if the path did change

Comment: @chedabob No, it doesn't replicate in the 6S simulator. It also doesn't crash on a fresh install of the app on a 6S. The only time it has happened was after restoring from iTunes.

Comment: @Mr.T I don't have access to the original device. It's from a user out in the wild who was able to email me the crash report.

Comment: @Mr.T The AppDelegate is being called from my BaseViewController awakeFromNib so that it can grab the managedObjectContext to access CoreData.

Comment: @BjörnRo No, I'm not storing anything. The function that is crashing is Xcode boilerplate that dynamically determines where to look for document files.

Comment: @KennyWyland Did you ever find a solution for this? Suddenly, I have lots of _exact_ error in the crash logs from Fabric, but I cannot reproduce this myself.

Answer (score 0):

Crashes without any useful stacktrace often happen when a message is sent to a deallocated instance. I struggled with this a few weeks ago when messing around with a UIViewController category.

Of course, you are right, a message sent to nil doesn't do no harm. A message sent to a deallocated instance of sth on the other hand leads to a crash.
Try turning ZombieObjects on, then you will get a log when this occurs, which can help you find the bug.

Comment: This isn't something I can replicate. It happened out in the wild and isn't a situation where I can rebuild the binary and try it again.

Comment: That's unfortunate. Still, for future testing (unless you want to see the memory usage in realtime), it doesn't hurt to enable ZombieObjects. Also, Instruments can be of help in such situations. Also keep an eye open for a delegate that is accidentally a strong ref for example. Good luck :)